# Javascript scope weirdness, function and browser

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, firefox, scope

I thought that doing this:

```
var what = function () {};
```

and this

```
function what () {}
```

was the same thing in JS, as functions are supposed to be "first class object".

Today I learned that in Firefox this code :

```
var test = true;
if (test) {
    function what () {
      alert("foo");
    }
} else {
    function what () {
      alert("bar");
    }
}
what();
```

display foo, and for weird reason chrome display bar... Why [number one] ?
Doing this :

```
var test = true, what;

    if (test) {
        what = function() {
          alert("foo");
        }
    } else {
        what = function () {
          alert("bar");
        }
    }
    what();
```

Solved the problem.. Why [number two]?
you can try it out http://jsfiddle.net/7cbs5gr7/ here

[Abstract] I have two questions :

1. Why chrome and firefox act differently on this ? -additional one : wich one is right ? -
2. Why setting the function explicitly in a var solved the problem ?

Comment: I smell a wacky issue of hoisting there. It would seem that Firefox doesn't hoist the function body the same way Chrome does. Setting the function in a `var` probably forced the hoisting one way or another, solving the issue. One more good reason to always hoist `var` declarations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Functions can be conditionally defined using either //function statements// (an allowed extension to the ECMA-262 Edition 3 standard) or the Function constructor. Please note that such function statements are no longer allowed in ES5 strict. Additionally, this feature does not work consistently cross-browser, so you should not rely on it.

Scroll to [Conditionally defining a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Conditionally_defining_a_function)

Answer (score 3):

Declaring a function like

```
what = function () {
    alert("foo");
}
```

and

```
function what () {
    alert("foo");
}
```

are two different things.

In the first case, the variable is hoisted and the function definition needs the script execution to be passed thru that point in `if` or `else`. In the second case, the function is just declared and can be accessed from anywhere regardless of the condition in `if` and `else`.

Comment: In OP's example the function is named when declared without a `var`.

Comment: In that case, hoisting would not be there, but the issue will still be there.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Conditionally_defining_a_function